# how to resolve mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in mysql , but it is giving me below error , can any one let me know what i am doing wrong

this is the error i am receiving.

> EXECUTE stmt USING company_id, evaluator_id, start_limit, endlimit
>        Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'company_id, evaluator_id, start_limit, endlimit' at    line 1
>   Error in query: 3

```
 DROP PROCEDURE evaluatorEvaluation;

 CREATE PROCEDURE evaluatorEvaluation(
    company_id INT(5),
    evaluator_id INT(5), 
    start_limit INT(3),  
    endlimit INT(5)
)
 PREPARE stmt from 'SELECT frt.agent_id, 
   frt.form_id, 
   frt.company_form_id, 
   frt.badge_assigned_id, 
   CONCAT_WS('', '', mt.lastname, mt.firstname) AS agent, 
   CONCAT_WS('', '', mt1.lastname, mt1.firstname) AS evaluator, 
   cft.form_name, 
   frt.chatter_msg_id, 
   frt.performance_level, 
   frt.achieved_percentage, 
   frt.agent_acceptance, 
   frt.evaluation_date, 
   frt.evaluator_id, 
   frt.exclude, 
   frt.coaching_date, 
   frt.searchable 
 FROM form_results_tbl frt 
 INNER JOIN company_form_tbl cft 
 LEFT JOIN members_tbl mt ON frt.agent_id = mt.user_id 
 LEFT JOIN members_tbl mt1 ON frt.evaluator_id = mt1.user_id 
 WHERE frt.company_form_id = cft.company_form_id 
 AND frt.company_id = ? AND frt.status IN(1,0) 
 AND frt.evaluator_id = ?
 AND cft.form_type=''internal''
 GROUP BY frt.form_id 
 ORDER BY frt.agent_acceptance DESC, 
     frt.evaluation_date DESC 
 LIMIT ?, ?;
 ';
 EXECUTE stmt USING company_id, evaluator_id, start_limit, endlimit;
```

Comment: There are multiple statements in your procedure you need a begin with an end and you need to set delimiters, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Also the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html is clear that you use user defined (at variables) in the using clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use stored procedure parameters directly, but assign values to internal variables:

```
DROP PROCEDURE evaluatorEvaluation;

 CREATE PROCEDURE evaluatorEvaluation(
    company_id INT(5),
    evaluator_id INT(5), 
    start_limit INT(3),  
    end_limit INT(5)
)
    SET @cid := company_id;
    SET @eid := evaluator_id; 
    SET @slimir := start_limit;  
    SET @elimit := end_limit;

 PREPARE stmt from 'SELECT frt.agent_id, 
   frt.form_id, 
   frt.company_form_id, 
   frt.badge_assigned_id, 
   CONCAT_WS('', '', mt.lastname, mt.firstname) AS agent, 
   CONCAT_WS('', '', mt1.lastname, mt1.firstname) AS evaluator, 
   cft.form_name, 
   frt.chatter_msg_id, 
   frt.performance_level, 
   frt.achieved_percentage, 
   frt.agent_acceptance, 
   frt.evaluation_date, 
   frt.evaluator_id, 
   frt.exclude, 
   frt.coaching_date, 
   frt.searchable 
 FROM form_results_tbl frt 
 INNER JOIN company_form_tbl cft 
 LEFT JOIN members_tbl mt ON frt.agent_id = mt.user_id 
 LEFT JOIN members_tbl mt1 ON frt.evaluator_id = mt1.user_id 
 WHERE frt.company_form_id = cft.company_form_id 
 AND frt.company_id = ? AND frt.status IN(1,0) 
 AND frt.evaluator_id = ?
 AND cft.form_type=''internal''
 GROUP BY frt.form_id 
 ORDER BY frt.agent_acceptance DESC, 
     frt.evaluation_date DESC 
 LIMIT ?, ?;
 ';
 EXECUTE stmt USING @cid, @eid, @slimit, @elimit;
```